# PHP / HTTP Timeout when using Large set of Curl Request

Tags: php, sql, http, curl, timeout

I have a PHP script which basically goes through my database (currently only about 200 rows)
check for XYZ urls and then trys to scrape them to see if an update value is available.

Now I set the timeout on curl to 5 seconds as shouldn't take longer than this for each request.

I have set the timeout on PHP (max timeout) to 0 - which is unlimited.

I can now successfully do sets of 40 or so rows by add LIMIT 40 to my sql cmd.

Currently I have the scrape in part of a loop for 'each row' returned by the SQL command.

This is ending in a HTTP timeout presumably because it isn't returned within a specific time.

Now my question is can I load each 'loop' too the page individually so you can see them appear as they are completed also this would resolve the HTTP timeout?

I dont have access to apache as its using standard hosting package.

Could any one assist me in the right direction to write this code so it doesn't timeout.

Hope this makes sense if you want me to go over anything above please let me know!

Comment: Could you show the main logic behind your code.

Comment: I have a curl function to scrape some data from a URL, the urls reside in my table.

I call the function in a 'for each row' loop this scraping all the urls.